# Passing parameters between xhtml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to pass a parameter between two xhtml, I have the next code for the first xhtm

```
<h:dataTable value="#{ofertaController.items}" var="item" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" rowClasses="jsfcrud_odd_row,jsfcrud_even_row" rules="all" style="border:solid 1px">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_idoferta}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.idoferta}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_fechaInicio}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaInicio}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_fechaFin}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaFin}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_descripcion}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.descripcion}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_precioInicial}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.precioInicial}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_precioFinal}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.precioFinal}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListOfertaTitle_negocioCif}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.negocioCif}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="&nbsp;"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.prepareView}" value="#{bundle.ListOfertaViewLink}"/>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.prepareEdit}" value="#{bundle.ListOfertaEditLink}"/>
                        <h:outputText value=" "/>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{ofertaController.destroy}" value="#{bundle.ListOfertaDestroyLink}"/>
                        <h:link outcome="/cupon/compra" value="Comprar">

                           <f:param name="idOferta" value="#{item.idoferta}" />

                        </h:link>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

As you can see I have a:

```
                    <h:link outcome="/cupon/compra" value="Comprar">

                       <f:param name="idOferta" value="#{item.idoferta}" />

                    </h:link>
```

And I get the next url:

```
http://localhost:8080/agrupados/faces/cupon/compra.xhtml?idOferta=1
```

This idOferta=1 I want to use it in a Managed bean but always, it appears as null, why?. The xhtml which I linked before is this one:

```
  <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateCuponLabel_email}" for="email" />
                    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{cuponController.selected.email}" title="#{bundle.CreateCuponTitle_email}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateCuponRequiredMessage_email}"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
                <br />

                <h:commandLink action="#{cuponController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateCuponSaveLink}" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{cuponController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateCuponShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.CreateCuponIndexLink}"/>
            <br/>
             <h:commandButton id="compra" value="COMPRAR" action="#{compra.addCompra}" />

            </h:form>
```

And the ManagedBean is this one where is the addCompra:

```
 @ManagedBean(name="compra")
    @RequestScoped

public class Compra {

    @EJB
        private NegocioFacade negocioFacade;
    @EJB
        private OfertaFacade ofertaFacade; 

     @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.idOferta}")
    private String idOferta;

    //(String) 


    public Compra() {

    }

    public void addCompra(){
        System.out.println(idOferta);
        FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String idoferta=ofer(fc);
        System.out.println(idoferta);
    }

    public String ofer(FacesContext fc){

        Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        return params.get("idOferta");
      }
    }
```

What can I do?, how can I get this idOferta=1?. Thanks so much for all guys

Answer (score 1):

you can use `f:viewParam` like this:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="idOferta" value="#{compra.idOferta}" />
</f:metadata>
```

just don't forget to add the getter-setter methods for idOferta to class compra, and remove the `@ManagedProperty` annotation.